# Can Sitecore be installed offline?

Tags: installation

Can Sitecore be installed offline?

I've only tried to install it online using the SIM, but SIM, or the current version need access to the internet, to run the SIM application.

So how to handle it offline, is copying the data, database and website folder into the inetpub directory enough?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, Sitecore can be installed in offline mode, or from machines without internet access.

The latest versions of Sitecore Instance Manager, since the version 1.5.0.2 release, supports [running in offline mode](https://twitter.com/jammykam/status/877639735942033410). Earlier versions were [not able to run in offline mode](https://www.jflh.ca/2016-07-22-run-sitecore-sim-tool-offline) but you should upgrade to the latest version (1.5.0.179) if you have not already done so.

You can also install Sitecore without the use of SIM. In all versions prior to 9 you are able to download an exe application installer, which will run offline, create the necessary IIS site + bindings, add the hosts file entry and attach the SQL databases:

[image: Application Installer]

Alternatively, you can install the application manually by downloading the zip archive of the site root folder, extracting the files, creating an IIS site + binding manually, attaching the SQL Server databases and then editing the Sitecore config files for your local set up. The installation process for both of these methods is heavily documented in the Sitecore Installation Guide for each version.

Comment: yes.. I have done what you mentioned above, with the bindings and everything.. but again I still like the SIM solution.. Where can I get my hands on the 1.5.0.2 version? doesn't seem to be able to find it anywhere?

Comment: SIM is a ClickOnce Application, the latest version (1.5.0.179) can be downloaded from http://dl.sitecore.net/updater/sim/. If you still have issues I suggest you uninstall your current version then re-install.

Comment: I tried the offline tutorial it does not seem to work..

Comment: I have no idea about the offline blog post, have never tried it. Like I said, the latest versions of SIM do work since I have done this myself several times, on a laptop without internet connection. If it does not work with SIM then suggest you raise an issue on the Github repo.

Comment: Hm... well i guess you ran it online first?.. if so, I am running for the first time offline..

Comment: It's a ClickOnce application. The only thing you download if the Manifest file and then install it (which then downloads the application files)... afaik, you can't install it offline, there is no standalone installer for SIM.